# Comments using Facebook Social Plugin doesn't post

Tags: facebook

I can’t post on any social media websites using the Facebook plugin. I type my comment and click comment, but it doesn't post. I created another Facebook account thinking something was wrong with my account, but I still have the same problem. I can post comments with the new account, but once I log out the comment disappears. I'm the only person who can see my comments using my new account. Any reason why my comments aren't posting on social media websites using Facebook plugin? Why aren't my comments seen by others using my new account? Why do they disappear when I log out? Do I have a setting wrong?

Comment: What is the "Facebook plugin"?

Comment: Facebook plugin are used on various websites to post comments using Facebook account. HLNTV uses Facebook plugins to make comments on their website. I cant post on any websites outside of Facebook using Facebook because the comments do not post. The comments cannot be seen by others by others when I log out of my account. I can see the comment, but others cannot because its not posting.

Comment: Are certain sites you are leaving comments on reviewing comments before they are posted to the site?

Comment: @jonsca No. The comments post immediately, but they aren't posting. I click post, but it doesn't post. The post doesn't stick. I did create another Facebook account and when I post it does post, but the posting isn't seen by others. When I log out and look at the forum, my comment is nowhere to be found. Nobody responds because my messages aren't posting on websites outside of Facebook. Its really weird....I can post on my timeline etc, but I cant post on websites outside of Facebook using Facebook. I'm sorry it took me a few days to get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Either the account you are using is somehow being blacklisted from commenting with the plugin or there is a bug.

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments and try there.

Also you can test it by placing another URL in the box

[image: Another URL]

If you think everything is in order and it is still giving problems, you will need to file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Here is a list of current bugs with social plugins https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/custom/?tag_ids=127928707302082

Comment: How do I file a bug? I dont see a create button. Thanks for helping me with this situation.

Comment: @JeanineHogan try searching first then the create button should popup else you can pop in at https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: Thanks. I did search, but I couldnt find any solution to this problem. It does seem like my account is blacklisted, but I dont know why or how I can undo it.

Comment: @JeanineHogan try to join facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers and see if you can state your problem there.